# Multi-page pdf using barryvdh dompdf Laravel-4 and loadView rather than loadHtml

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-4

I'm trying to create batched pdf invoices (using: [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)) that can be downloaded and printed. Sending the invoices via email is easy because the 'send' command works perfectly inside a loop and will attach the currently created pdf, but $pdf->download() requires a return response -- my attempts to download without "return" get an error message, and "return" of course breaks the loop. Since my invoices are complicated, I'm using

```
    $pdf->loadView('invoices.show',$data);
```

to create the invoice using a view, rather than trying to write all of the html in the controller. I'm fine with combining all of the invoices into a single, multi-page pdf. I understand the trick of using css style="page-break-after" to create different pages, but I can't figure out how to do that when I'm using loadView in order to send page-specific $data, rather than loadHtml -- loadView always results in only the last invoice being included.

For example, controller:

```
public function invoices()
{
    $pdf = App:make('dompdf');
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $data = array('i'=>$i);
    }
$pdf->loadView('invoices.show',$data);
return $pdf->download("Invoice");
}
```

(I'm only including a single variable in the example $data array here; the real invoices obviously have a lot of $data variables.)

View, wrapped in:

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;">
```

Only returns, where the Invoice # = $i

```
Invoice #3
```

Of course, putting $pdf->loadView inside of the loop does exactly the same thing. And since $pdf is not a string, trying something like $pdf .= ... within the loop doesn't work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your `loadView` isn't in the loop, it's just outside the for so when it's called, `$data` has the last value of the loop, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as I discovered, is simply to put any required loop in the view, not in the controller. That works fine.

Answer (score 2):

We need generate a PDF file with multiple pages, in laravel 5 and with blade template.

In this post, we found a solution of how dompdf create document:
[convert multiple html to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657525/how-to-convert-multiple-html-files-with-dompdf/27658136#27658136)

My solution:
I create 2 blade templates, container.blade and content.blade.
First, i send data from my controller to content.blade into a foreach loop

```
loop...

view2 = View::make('contentview', compact('data'))->render();
$viewfinal = $viewfinal.$view2;

..endloop
```

$viewfinal is a concatenation of all html generating code of HEADS and BODYS from blade templates. 
And finally:

```
$view = View::make('containerview', compact('viewfinal'))->render();
```

containerview.blade, only have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{!! $viewfinal !!}
</html>
```

And content.blade generate pages with "head" and "body", but **NOT "html" tag**, one for each PDF page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>


<title>Multiples pages</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/impresion1.css">
 </head><body> ...........</body>
```