# how to convert multiple html files with Dompdf?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

#### What I am Doing:

I am using a PHP library called [`Dompdf`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) to convert my HTML file into PDF.
I have successful converted a single HTML file to PDF.

#### What I am trying to do:

Now I have multiple reports I want to convert them into PDF file.

#### What I am doing:

I have a example here in which I'm a getting a form from database and another one by direct from view.

**Code:**

```
$result['patients'] = $this->reports_model->get_xray_reports($id); // getting form from database

require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"; // include dompdf
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4");
$html = $this->load->view('wilcare/form_set_page_15',"",true);// loading direct from view
//this file is not converting
$html = $this->load->view('wilcare/report1',$result,true);//loading from db

$dompdf->load_html($html)

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
```

#### Problem

It is only converting one file.

**I have also tried this:**

```
  $html = $this->load->view('wilcare/form_set_page_15',"",true);
  $html1 = $this->load->view('wilcare/report1',$result,true);

  $dompdf->load_html($html && $html1);
```

Comment: you are first overwriting the `$html` variable. Also you need to have two different filenames otherwise you'll overwrite your file.

Comment: one file containing, to create document!

Comment: yes @hakre i you are right!

Comment: I've now looked into DOMPDF and tested this a little, it does not work with string concatenation but with **DOMDocument** in PHP (use as well by DOMPDF internally) there are quite some options. Demo PDFs included: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27658136/367456

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to create on PDF file from two HTML files with DOMPDF.

This is not possible. DOMPDF supports the creation of one PDF file from one HTML document.

Internally DOMPDF uses **DOMDocument** to represent the HTML document. So if you want to put two HTML files into DOMPDF you have to merge these first.

### DOMPDF HTML merge behavior

Testing did reveal that you can concatenate mutlitple `<head>...</head><body>...</body>` sections (each of these pairs will start a new page in DOMPDF) but they need to be inside the same `<html>` document element (DOMPDF v0.6.1).

If you merge elements inside the `<body>` element then a single page is created.

If you append multiple `<html>` documents just after another (as suggested by Simo), the only the first document is put into the PDF.

I add two PHP examples:

1. The first one shows how to merge two HTML documents into a single body which DOMPDF renders as one page ([PDF](http://tinyurl.com/nrv78br))
2. The second shows how to merge them into the two `<head>...</head><body>...</body>` which DOMPDF renders as two pages ([PDF](http://tinyurl.com/oe4odmy))

### PHP Example Code HTML document merging DOMPDF single body

E.g. you want to append the body contents of the second HTML document to the end of the body of the first one (all objects of type **DOMDocument**).
:

```
$doc1 = create_document(1);
$doc2 = create_document(2);

$doc1Body = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$doc2Body = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($doc2Body->childNodes as $child) {
    $import = $doc1->importNode($child, true);
    if ($import) {
        $doc1Body->appendChild($import);
    }
}
$doc1->saveHTMLFile('php://output');
```

Exemplary HTML Output ([of this full Example Code](https://eval.in/237214)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Document 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Document 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
<p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
<h1>Document 2</h1>
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Creates this PDF: http://tinyurl.com/nrv78br (one page)

### PHP Example Code HTML document merging DOMPDF multiple pages

Here the example with a new page on the second HTML document:

```
foreach ($doc2->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
    $import = $doc1->importNode($child, true);
    if ($import) {
        $doc1->documentElement->appendChild($import);
    }
}
$html = $doc1->saveHTML();
```

Exemplary HTML Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Document 1</title></head><body>
<h1>Document 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
<p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
</body><head><title>Document 2</title></head><body>
<h1>Document 2</h1>
<p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.2</p>
</body></html>
```

Creates this PDF: http://tinyurl.com/oe4odmy (two pages)

---

Depending on what you need with your documents, you might need to do additional steps, like merging the title and CSS rules (which hopefully are portable).

Comment: FYI, utilizing the HTML5 parsing engine available since v0.6.0 will clean up your document such that there is only a single body element, and thus no page break.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the two files :

```
//this file is not converting
$html .= $this->load->view('wilcare/report1',$result,true);
```

Comment: If you print $html variable after merging, what it's showing ?

Comment: its getting both file but converting only one.

Comment: maybe because you have an invalid html file, or some closing tags are missing, try to validate the whole file (merged One).

Comment: I'm not specifically versatile with DOMPDF but I would not expect the library to actually handle the concatenation of HTML documents.